ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmcv.parallel'
  File "c:\Users\Nakul\OneDrive\Documents\finalyear_project\mmfashion\newtry.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mmfashion.apis import init_detector, inference_detector
  File "c:\Users\Nakul\OneDrive\Documents\finalyear_project\mmfashion\mmfashion\apis\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .test_fashion_recommender import test_fashion_recommender
  File "c:\Users\Nakul\OneDrive\Documents\finalyear_project\mmfashion\mmfashion\apis\test_fashion_recommender.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mmcv.parallel import MMDataParallel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmcv.parallel'

I have checked all the dependencies and it matches with my requirement.txt file from mmfashion github repo still facing error. Kindly help me.

Run: pip install -U openmim and then mim install mmcv command
